# Does a Python get request to an asp page impact on the response?

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to download a bundle of reports (PDF and XLSX) from a website.

I had a working solution that is now failing as the important GET request is now responding with

```
{'result': 'redirect', 'url': '../warning.asp?header=Report has expired&body=Your report has already expired.  Please select a report from the menu.&footer='}
```

Executing the necessary login, report selection and output steps in postman works perfectly. The same under python is giving me the above problem.

I can login into the actual website and trace the various steps. I note that one step opens a new browser window and then automatically starts to download the report.

The code is pretty basic

```
    rw = session.get('https://website.com.au/Reports/ReportWindow.asp?' + report_urlencoded)

    if rw.status_code == 200:
        print('https://website.com.au/reports/generatereport.asp?_=' + str(current_milli_time()))
        gr = session.get('https://website.com.au/reports/generatereport.asp?_=' + str(current_milli_time()))
```

The line

```
 rw = session.get('https://website.com.au/Reports/ReportWindow.asp?' + report_urlencoded)
```

opens a new window and the automatically proceeds to download the requested report (if I use an actual browswer)

The above run in postman does exactly what I want it do.

What I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Some sites avoid stripting requests checking the headers.
Try adding valid headers (you can copy the code from your postman request code for python requests).

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite work out what I did to fix it, but I suspect that sending some fairly standard headers as part of the request has probably fixed it.

It may also been that I was not properly logged in despite getting back 200 response (which I had assumed was logged in but maybe not)